# How can I plot signal statistics(variance) of subintervals in the same graph with signal plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I calculated the variance for subintervals in my signal. The result is a vector that I would like to plot in the same graph as the signal below. How can I plot the variance for each subinterval? What type of plot should I use? Histogram or boxplot?[image]

Comment: Hi, your question confuses me. First, what's a subinterval? But more importantly, what do you want to do? You start with a simple line -- add std representation around your mean. For that just use matplotlib [fill between lines](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-fill-between-demo-py). But then you're asking how to plot your std and mention histogram and boxplot which totally doesn't make sense with respect to the first part. Either you want to show errors of the mean or the distribution(s) of such errors.

Comment: I have a set of 7860 values that I divided into 20 equal intervals. For each I calculated the variance which has this values ([0.06057497068018203, 0.2921903202797406, 0.26130194652200645, 0.6572348814173657, 0.21491131550763803, 0.5220988449198373, 0.032965663897601985, 0.052615615996826896, 0.6022333139843596, 0.17343183929030717])
 and I would like to plot it in the same graph with the original signal to show how my signal varies.

Comment: The problem is that I have 7680 samples on x axis for original signal and on the y axis are the signal values. When I try to plot variance I have this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (20,) and (7680,).

Comment: Well, that's not surprising :D, ok, I'm beginning to understand. So just let me clarify. You want to overlay this time series with some barplot/histplot which would show the variance in the given interval. Ie., not the variance of the mean but the variance of the interval.

Comment: Exactly!  my signal represents a person's breathing rate and I want to calculate how it varies from one interval to another and  represent this on the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to overlay the time series with the bar plot of std in the given interval, you can just simply plot it in the same graph by specifying the positions of the bars. Here it's the centre of the interval which you can get many ways, even manually. Then you can set the width of the bars to whatever pleases your eyes, but in my opinion, it's looking nice if it has approximately the same width as the interval. An example comes below in `matplotlib`. However, the axis will likely not be corresponding (ie. the scale of your std is likely not going to match the scale of your signal). Thus I'd recommend using two axes.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create data
n = 100
n_segments = 5
y = np.random.randint(100, size=n)
stds = np.std(y.reshape(n_segments,-1), axis=1)

# get the midpoints
x = np.linspace(n//(2*n_segments),n-n//(2*n_segments),n_segments)

# Sol A
plt.plot(range(n),y)
plt.bar(x, stds, width=n//(n_segments)-1, alpha=0.4)

# Sol B with twin axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(range(n),y, 'g-')
ax2.bar(x, stds, width=n//(n_segments)-1, alpha=0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so, so much, it works now. Do you know what a should use to plot trendline? I calculated trend with polyfit and I would like to plot in my graph something like an arrow to suggest whether the trend increases or decreases for each interval depending on the slope value obtained using polyfit (if the first value in the resulting vector is positive, the trend increases and vice versa).

Comment: You should ask a separate question about this. It's unrelated to this problem and it's not a good practice to ask follow up questions in comments.

Comment: I already asked 11 days ago in another post :)